# In a Text file I need to print only last character Is Possible

Tags: java, string

In a Text file I need to print only last character Is Possible
Example Input

```
Steve Jobs
Android
Apple
Core Java
Facebook(Assume Its in file name Sample)
```

Output

```
Input 
droid
pple
book
```

Comment: edit your question with exact input and expected output.

Comment: And why you expect that output... No Jobs? Why droid?

Comment: what the pattern you are following for all inputs???

Comment: I am a beginner level person I do core java Project That why I asked

Comment: @identicon how you are generating output in identical manner from all the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not clear. You can get the last charactor by

```
String str = "awesome";
System.out.println(str.charAt(str.length()-1));
```

Output

```
e
```

You can manipulate this in order to get what you expect.